# How to verify the API response status in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, httparty

I am using HTTParty gem to make request in my Rails application.

1. Making POST request to generate a report
2. Making GET request to check status of report
3. Download report after report status is completed

I need to make above GET request until report status is completed. Report status will take some time to update the status.

How can I efficiently check the status of report?

```
def get_report(id)
// making requests
end

report = get_report(3)
report['status']
```

Comment: `while get_report(3)['status'] == 'pending'; sleep(10); end;` and then execute the `post` request

Comment: I want to download the report after report status is completed. Did you mean to execute get request after while loop

Comment: I'm suggesting that you: 1- call the generate report; 2- call a loop to check on the report's status every 10 seconds; 3- once the report is `done`, you call the download api; unless the download API is the same than the status check, then you need to update the answer with the API response so we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ActiveJob to do that kind of process. The usage is as following.

```
 class ReportingGenerationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  after_perform do |job|
    ReportGenrator.notify_ready_to_download(job.arguments.first)
  end

  def perform(report_id)
    ReportGenerator.generate(report_id) #Your ReportGenerator has to expose api for get the current status
  end
end
```